# Mysql ORDER BY primary key slow down because of JOIN

Tags: sql, join, view

I have 3 tables in cascade patient(250 000 recors)-patient_attributes(250 000 recors)-examination(1 000 000 recors)
patient:patient_attributes is 1:N
patient_attributes:examination is 1:N

query1 is quite fast (0.000sec):

```
SELECT examination.ID AS Eid 
FROM examination  
ORDER BY eid LIMIT 10000,50
```

query2 is still fast (0.015sec):

```
SELECT examination.ID AS Eid 
FROM examination
JOIN `patient_attributes` 
  ON `examination`.`PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES_ID` = `patient_attributes`.`ID`
ORDER BY eid LIMIT 10000,50
```

query3 is quite slow (5.5sec):

```
SELECT examination.ID AS Eid 
FROM `examination`         
JOIN `patient_attributes` 
  ON `examination`.`PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES_ID` = `patient_attributes`.`ID`      
JOIN `patient` ON  `patient_attributes`.`PATIENT_ID` = `patient`.`ID`
ORDER BY eid LIMIT 10000,50
```

The joins are useless in this case for simplicity. Later I would like to create view from this query and I would except DB to omit the unused columns in the view and omit the unused joins, because these joins are joined via foreign keys and there is allways one record.

Should I set something in db structure to speed up the query3, to omit the useless joins in the query?

```
examination.ID is primary key, 
examination.PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES_ID is foreign key, 
patient_attributes.ID is primary key, 
patient_attributes.PATIENT_ID is foreign key, 
patient.ID is primary key

show index from patient

Table   Non_uniq Key_name    Seq_in_index Column_name Collation Cardinality Sub_part Packed Null Index_type
patient 0        PRIMARY     1            ID                 A    230077    NULL    NULL         BTREE  
patient 1        RefMEMO1001 1            ANAMNESIS_MEMO_ID  A    80        NULL    NULL    YES  BTREE  
patient 1        REF17       1            RACE_ID            A    4         NULL    NULL    YES  BTREE  
patient 1        REF5        1            CARD_INDEX_ID      A    6         NULL    NULL         BTREE

show index from patient_attributes

Table         Non_unique Key_name Seq_in_idx Col.name Collation Cardinality Sub_part Packed Null Index_type
patient_attributes   0   PRIMARY         1   ID               A    1857048     NULL    NULL       BTREE  
patient_attributes   1   RefPATIENT1021  1   PATIENT_ID       A    619016      NULL    NULL       BTREE  
patient_attributes   1   RefMEMO1081     1   SYMPTOMS_MEMO_ID A    2           NULL    NULL  YES  BTREE

show index from examination

Table   Non_unique Key_name      Seq_in_index  Column_name   Collation Cardinality Sub_part Packed Null Index_type
examination   0    PRIMARY                   1 ID                    A 905353      NULL      NULL       BTREE  
examination   0    I_EXAMINATION_GUID        1 UNIQUE_GUID           A 905353      NULL      NULL       BTREE  
examination   0    I_PATIENT_GUID            1 UNIQUE_GUID           A 905353      NULL      NULL       BTREE  
examination   1    RefSTATION621             1 STATION_ID            A 2           NULL      NULL  YES  BTREE  
examination   1    I_EXAMINATION_STATUS      1 STATUS                A 6           NULL      NULL       BTREE  
examination   1    I_EXAMINATION_CREATED     1 CREATED               A 181070      NULL      NULL       BTREE  
examination   1    I_EXAMINATION_STARTED     1 STARTED               A 181070      NULL      NULL       BTREE  
examination   1    RefPATIENT_ATTRIBUTES1031 1 PATIENT_ATTRIBUTES_ID A 905353      NULL      NULL       BTREE
```

Comment: So you only want rows 10,001 to 10,050?

Comment: Yes, I want only rows 10,001 to 10,050, it is simulation of paging in grid. If I change the query to Limit 0,50 it takes still 5.5sec.

Comment: So all of the IDs in the joins etc. are indexed?

Comment: I have included the list of all indexes in these tables

Comment: THe particular database you are using will make a differnce inteh answer I suspect. HOwwever why do you think the joins are useless? That database will join to them if you have them in the query or view whether you think they are useless or not. It is up to you to determine which joins you need not the database.

Comment: I would like to create the DB view over about 5 tables. In the UI there will be grid with configurable columns. In defaults with few basic columns. I would like to make simple fast query if there are only few basic columns in the grid.

Comment: The database has to do the join to get the correct answer. Suppose that patient does it actually exist, then there will be 0 rows. If the database doesn't actually do the join, then it may not return the right number of rows. To get to row 10000, it must know if the previous 10000 all exist.

Comment: That seems to bring out why it joins the tables if not in select. OK. But still there is primary foreign key between patient and patients_attributes and I would suppose that the query need not to run over 5 seconds. I presume that the database should iterate throu the foreign key to satisfy the query optimalization. Am I right?